# How to use nested routes in Django

Tags: python, django, routes, django-rest-framework

I have started using Django in my new project and I am stuck with problem. I would like to declare a route like

```
POST /user/disqualify?user_id=<value>
```

Attributes such has `user_id` will be passed as query parameters. I understand we are deviating too much from RESTful url guidelines, but I still would like to know how can I handle such url in Django2.

My current url definition looks

```
url('^user', User.as_view(), name='user'),
```

and `User` is subclass of `APIView`.

**Note**

- Consider the weird url as my limitation. This is due to pre-defined API Contract.

Comment: What's nested about this? `user_id` is a querystring parameter, which is not part of the URL but is available in `request.data` in DRF.

Comment: You already handle it, the `user_id` is *not* part of the path, but part of the *querystring*. You can obtain the value with `request.GET['user_id']`.

Comment: @DanielRoseman By nested I mean `disqualify`. Since it is an action that needs to be taken on resource `user`. There can be other actions as well in future like `/approve`, `/reviewed` etc.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I have `POST /user` call which invokes `post()` of `User` class. Now, I am not sure how to link `POST /user/disqualify` to a method in `User` class.

Comment: A POST request can still have a `querystring` and thus `request.GET`, but I find the syntax weird. What iss wrong with `POST /user/123/disqualifying`?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I agree It is wierd, but I got this predefined API contract. So consider this as my limitation. 
Also, accessing `user_id` is not real issue, but mapping url to function is.

Comment: So why can't you define your URL pattern as `^user/disqualify$`?

Comment: @DanielRoseman That's exactly what i am doing, but since i am new to Django, so i am not sure if there is better way for it.

Comment: Well there might be but we don't have enough details of how the rest of your URLs are structure. For example, if you're using a Router, see this: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/#routing-for-extra-actions